# Removing elements from list of lists based on user choice in Racket

Tags: list, racket

As the question shows, I'm trying to take user input to remove elements from a list of lists.
The list is formatted as so.
`'((X X X) (X X X X) (X X))` where each sublist contains an arbitrary amount of X's.

The user chooses 1,2,3,... for each of the sublists. So if the user types 1, the sublist `'(X X  X)` gets chosen. The user then chooses how many of the elements to remove.

The current code I have for this is as follows.

```
(define (humanTurn rows player playerNumber)
    (drawBoard (with-handlers ([exn:fail?
                                  (lambda (exn)
                                      (display 
                                           "ILLEGAL MOVE, PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBER\n"))])
                              (getRowAndSticks rows))
               (list (first (rest player)) (first player)) 
               (cond [(equals? playerNumber 1) 2]
                     [(equals? playerNumber 2) 1]
                     [else "error"])))

(define (getRowAndSticks rows)
    (list-tail (list-ref rows (sub1 (getRow)))
               (begin
                   (display "How many sticks:........ ")
                   (read))))

(define (getRow)
    (display "Which row do you choose: ")
    (read))
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to append the list back together. I've only managed to get the list that I've removed the elements from. I don't see any solution, because I'm not allowed to use variables.

Comment: Working on some CS400 from CSM, eh?

Comment: Yes... I've been working on it for 15 hours straight.

Comment: I fixed your code formatting to be in line with scheme conventions. Please make sure I didn't change any meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time following your code, but for joining lists back together use either the `list` function or the `list*`.  The difference between  the two is that the latter makes a list of all the arguments except for the last one which is sort of tacked on.

Comment: The thing was, I couldn't figure out how to get the start and end of the main list. I finally got it, by reversing the list, tailing it, then reversing it back. Appending that, then appending the fixed sublist, then doing the same for the end. But now, I'm stuck because the with-handlers isn't catching and repeating the question. But that's another problem :\